# Avoid repeating codes when defining `tcolorbox` environments

Tags: tcolorbox

Is there a way to factorize the following code in which the only difference between the environments `doclatex` and `doclatex-flat` is about the use of `listing side text`?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{%
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    left   = 1mm, right = 1mm,
    bottom = 1mm, top   = 1mm,
    listing side text
}

\newtcblisting{doclatex-flat}{
    breakable,
    sharp corners,
    left   = 1mm, right = 1mm,
    bottom = 1mm, top   = 1mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\begin{doclatex-flat}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex-flat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should be able to use `\tcbset` to define a style which defines the common settings and then can then be used in two spots.

Comment: @PeterGrill Ok, I look at that, and thereafter I try to answer my own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcolorbox`'s key-val scheme is from `pgfkeys`, which is auto loaded by either `pgf` or `tikz`. So you can define a style key using `/.style` key handler.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{minted, breakable}

\tcbset{
    doc latex common/.style={
        breakable,
        sharp corners,
        left   = 1mm, right = 1mm,
        bottom = 1mm, top   = 1mm,
    }
}

\newtcblisting{doclatex}{%
    doc latex common,
    listing side text
}

\newtcblisting{doclatex-flat}{
    doc latex common,
    bottom = 1mm, top   = 1mm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{doclatex}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex}

\begin{doclatex-flat}
$just + A = test$
\end{doclatex-flat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!